# Send image to java service from php

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a situation, where in my project for file upload, i have to send that image to java service(in multipart format), so that they can upload image from their side.
I have tried sending that image to java service in multiple ways,
I have used curl methods to send file to java service.
But no method worked for me.
If we do File uploading via postman, its hitting java service and successfully uploading the image.

I have mentioned a sample code which i have tried.
If anyone knows how to do this.

```
$path = 'http://10.10.10.113:8765/cojoin-service/api/image/upload';
   
$arrInputs = $arrKeyset;
if ( isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) ) {
    $filename  = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
    $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
                
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
```

Comment: Postman can help you generate valid PHP/Curl code equivalent to the successful request you made there. There's an automated code generator built into it.

Comment: @ADyson Can we know, what type of functionality is using in postman to upload a file, so that i can make changes in code according to them.

Comment: Yes. If you use the code generator as I suggested, it should create the PHP code for you automatically. Did you try? And to understand what functionality is being used, you just have to look at the relevant parts of the settings for that request. Of course, if you don't understand any of the basics of how a HTTP request works then you won't understand what you're looking at. You do need to have that basic knowledge in order to use these tools.